# Integrality gap and complexity classes

Tags: complexity-theory, optimization, complexity-classes, integer-programming

I would like to know if there exist some complexity classes that are defined according to the integrality gap of their problems?

In particular, is there a class of problems for which their integrality gap is unbounded?

Where by unbounded integrality gap, I mean an integrality gap that is equal to infinite, where the value of the relaxation is 0. For example, the min-diff Partition problem has an unbounded integrality gap.

Comment: Please ask only one question per post.  If you have multiple questions, you can post them separately (but make sure to include appropriate context and show your research).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is incorrect. The integrality gap is defined for a linear programming formulation of the problem and not fundamentally for the problem.

It is possible that a problem has more than one integer programming formulations, with some having unbounded integrality gap and the others having bounded integrality gap.

For example, see this paper on the [capacitated k-median problem](https://cse.buffalo.edu/%7Eshil/papers/CKMNonUniform-SODA2016.pdf) or see this statement from the book [The Design of Approximation Algorithms](https://www.designofapproxalgs.com/book.pdf#page=167) ([Page 167, last paragraph](https://www.designofapproxalgs.com/book.pdf#page=167)).

Comment: Ok, but consider the following. Maybe, one can prove that if a problem has an integer programming formulation having an unbounded integrality gap, then, one can show that the problem does not admit an FPTAS. In this case, we can find a relation between integrality gaps and complexity classes. Of course, I don't know if the last claim is true, but it shows that a relation can be found.

Comment: @SamuelBismuth I would want to see an example for this: "Maybe, one can prove that if a problem has an integer programming formulation having an unbounded integrality gap, then, one can show that the problem does not admit an FPTAS"? Only then I can comment on it.

Comment: The min-diff Partition problem has an integer program with an unbounded integrality gap, and no FPTAS, while the min-max Partition problem has an FPTAS. This is only an example, I asked if some proved theorems associating integrality gaps of problems with complexity classes exist.

Comment: @SamuelBismuth Is there a reduction that shows no FPTAS using unbounded integrality gap?

Comment: I am not sure that I understand the question.

Comment: @SamuelBismuth Let is move this discussion to [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146185/integrality-gap-and-complexity-classes).